# Problems with input values to a list

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm quite new at this and I have a problem. I want to read an input and store it at a list, for example:

```
2 -> number of trees that will be formed after this all
2 -> number of nodes of the first tree
1 -> node 1
2 -> node 2
1 -> number of nodes of the second tree
2 -> node 1
```

The code below doesn't work as I wanted. That means for example, using the input before:

```
2 -> number of trees that will be formed after this all
2 -> number of nodes of the first tree
1 -> number of nodes of the second tree
2 -> node 1 of the second tree
1 -> node 1 of the first tree
2 -> node 2 of the first tree
```

Output that the program shows for the input above is:
`1 2 2`

But I expected to have this:
`1 2 1`
How I can fix this?

```
let rec inputs number_of_nodes =
  match number_of_nodes with 
  | 0 -> []
  | _ -> let a = read_int() in a :: (inputs (number_of_nodes - 1))


let rec fill_tree_values number_of_trees = 
  match number_of_trees with
  | 0 -> []
  | _ -> let number_of_nodes = read_int() in 
    (inputs number_of_nodes) :: fill_tree_values (number_of_trees - 1)


let number_of_trees = read_int()
let trees = fill_tree_values number_of_trees

let printlist l = List.iter (Printf.printf "%d ") l

let () = List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) trees
```

Comment: Can you specify exactly what _output_ you are seeing, and what you're expecting?

Comment: Note: `List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) valores_listados` can be written as `List.iter printlist valores_listados`

Comment: (Hi, I just renamed the variables of the given code for clarity, sorry for inconsistencies with existing comments)

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with this code, so I think there's likely a mismatch in your expectations of output.

Comment: @Chris Basically the output that I see is ```1 2 2``` but I wanted ```1 2 1```

Comment: @Maëlan THANK YOU SOOO MUCH, it finally works as I wanted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```ml
    (inputs number_of_nodes) :: fill_tree_values (number_of_trees - 1)
```

but the evaluation order between both operands of `::` is unspecified. So it might very well be the case — and unless I’m mistaken, it is *effectively* the case — that they are evaluated right-to-left, i.e. `fill_tree_values (number_of_trees - 1)` is performed before `inputs number_of_nodes`. So you’re reading inputs in a broken order. You can test this right-to-left behavior:

```ml
let _ = print_int 1 :: print_int 2 :: print_int 3 :: []
(* with OCaml 4.12, this prints me "321" *)
```

You must enforce the evaluation order by rewriting your code as:

```ml
    let trees = inputs number_of_nodes in
    trees :: fill_tree_values (number_of_trees - 1)
```

Note: I believe the evaluation order around `::` might change in cutting-edge versions of OCaml, with the introduction of the “tail-call-modulo-constructor” optimisation. In any case, you should not rely on it.

Comment: The Tail-call-modulo-constructor transformation is opt-in, and will probably remain opt-in for years. Moreover, it does not change really change the order of evaluation of `::` (or any other constructors), it is rather that the transformation might rewrite such calls without preserving the order of evaluation (TMC is a whole-function transformation).

Comment: It may be worth noting your answer that order of evaluation is really only important when incorporating functions which have side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Maëlan has written about order of evaluation in his answer, you can achieve this as well by using tail recursion.

For example, a `read_ints` function that reads `n` ints.

```
let read_ints n =
  let rec aux n acc =
    if n = 0 then acc
    else aux (n - 1) (read_int () :: acc)
  in
  aux n [] |> List.rev
```

The very act of building the accumulator makes order of evaluation explicit.

Of course, that's not where you had a problem, but rather with:

> ```
> let rec fill_tree_values number_of_trees = 
>  match number_of_trees with
>  | 0 -> []
>  | _ -> let number_of_nodes = read_int() in 
>    (inputs number_of_nodes) :: fill_tree_values (number_of_trees - 1)
> ```

But we can apply the same strategy and now there's no ambiguous order of evaluation.

```
let fill_tree_values number_of_trees =
  let rec aux n acc =
    if n = 0 then acc
    else aux (n - 1) (inputs (read_int ()) :: acc)
  in
  aux number_of_trees [] |> List.rev
```

We *could* generalize this with a function which takes a function.

```
let map_times n f =
  let rec aux n' f acc =
    if n' = n then acc
    else let c = f n' in aux (n'+1) f (c :: acc)
  in
  aux 0 f [] |> List.rev
```

And then if we know we need to read `n` ints:

```
let fill_tree_values number_of_trees =
  map_times 
    number_of_trees 
    (fun _ -> 
       let n = read_int () in
       map_times n (fun _ -> read_int ()))
```

And then if we're really smart, we realize that we could just use `List.init` to do the exact same thing.

```
let fill_tree_values number_of_trees =
  List.(
    init number_of_trees (fun _ -> 
      let n = read_int () in
      init n (fun _ -> read_int ())
    )
  )
```

```
utop # fill_tree_values 2;;
2
3
4
1
5
- : int list list = [[3; 4]; [5]]
```